# sub pages is not becoming active

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Here am having add,view and edit pages.when i click on add and view pages the page is becoming active and the parent is also becoming active.but when i click on edit page which is shown in the view page the parent is not becoming active.
here is my view page

```
<li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Room Management <b class="fa fa-plus dropdown-plus"></b> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='add_class') echo "active";?>"> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/add_class"> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Add Class</a> </li>
          <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='view_class') echo "active";?>"> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/view_class"> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>View Class</a> </li>
          <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='add_rooms') echo "active";?>"> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/add_rooms"> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Add Rooms</a> </li>
          <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='view_rooms') echo "active";?>"> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/view_rooms"> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>View Rooms</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

from the view page am going to edit page and here is the code

```
 <td><a class="btn btn-success active" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/edit_hostel/<?php echo $row->id ?>"> Edit </a> </td>
```

here is the script where i had used menus to become active

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 var url = window.location;
 $('ul.dropdown-menu a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('open active');
 $('ul.dropdown-menu a').filter(function() {
  return this.href == url;
 }).parent().parent().parent().addClass('open active');
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the [contains pseudoselector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)

```
 var url = window.location;
     $('ul.dropdown-menu a[href*="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('open active').closest('li').addClass('open active');
 });
```

Comment: still it looks same

Comment: no changes happened..and i had changed my code to like this and this works

Comment: still appears same

Comment: what do you mean by "edit page which is shown in the view page"

Answer (score 0):

```
 <li class="dropdown <?php if($active_mn=='view_class'|| $active_mn=='view_rooms') echo "open active";?>"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Room Management <b class="fa fa-plus dropdown-plus"></b> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='add_class') echo "active";?>"> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/add_class"> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Add Class</a> </li>
          <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='view_class') echo "active";?>"> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/view_class"> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>View Class</a> </li>
          <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='add_rooms') echo "active";?>"> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/add_rooms"> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Add Rooms</a> </li>
          <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='view_rooms') echo "active";?>"> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/view_rooms"> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>View Rooms</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```